# Why is the geolocation not working when I loop through locations

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have various locations that I use for establishing a persons location but want to use geolocation if available, which is the number 1 element (2nd) of the locations array. If I use the code it does not return a position (new google.map.LatLng) at all. Does anyone know if there is something wrong with my code or what the problem could be.

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

  var newLat = parseFloat(locations[i][1]) + (Math.random() -.5) / 1500;
  var newLng = parseFloat(locations[i][2]) + (Math.random() -.5) / 1500;

  if(i == 1){
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
         });
      } else {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLng);
      }
  } else {
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat, newLng);        
  }
```

}

Comment: If you want to use geolocation with "the 1st element of the locations array" that would be when i = 0, as in Javascript arrays are zero-indexed (i.e array[0] is the first element).  Change to `if(i === 0){`

Comment: Sorry it is the number 1 element and not the first which would be 0. Although it doesn't really matter for this exercise. I have changed the question. Thx

Comment: geolocation is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Thx all for comments. I fixed it by getting the current location outside the loop and just checking for a value inside the loop.